# Programming question for Time Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, time

Can you program a sketch so that if the time is between 1m and 10m then it will reset itself?
Reset I found already, it is the if that I don't know.

Comment: Are you trying to reset your board every 1 minute? Because when it sees that time is a bit more than 1 minute it will reset. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Are you struggling with if() statements?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the timer interrupts. For example:

```
#define F_CPU   16000000UL
#include <avr/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
...
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{

  //do something every seconds when interrupt is raised.

}
void setup()
{
/*the following code will setup timer register to generate interrupt
  when 15624 is reached, at a clock frequency of 16 MHz and 1024 prescaler. This means that     every second an interrupt is generated
*/
  cli();          // disable global interrupts
  TCCR1A = 0;     // set entire TCCR1A register to 0
  TCCR1B = 0;     // same for TCCR1B

  // set compare match register to desired timer count:
  OCR1A = 15624;
  // turn on CTC mode:
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
  // Set CS10 and CS12 bits for 1024 prescaler:
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10);
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);
  // enable timer compare interrupt:
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
  sei();          // enable global interrupts
}
```

The code works on Arduino Uno. You should calculate the value of OCR1A for your frequency.